# Truncated SVD attribute python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svd, decomposition

I'm using [this tutorial code](https://github.com/mbernico/CS570/blob/master/LSA%20Text.ipynb) in my study.

Line to line it works well.But in the line

```
lsa.components_[0]
```

> AttributeError: 'TruncatedSVD' object has no attribute 'components_'

I think the codes work well before this line, and tutorial says TruncatedSVD has atrtibute components_, but I don't know how can I solve the problem.
I'm using python 2.7 in anaconda2 environment, but I tried eclipse pydev also, same error message appeared.

Comment: Did you definitely run `lsa.fit(X)` before accessing `lsa.components_`? From looking at [the source for `TruncatedSVD`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/51a765a/sklearn/decomposition/truncated_svd.py), `components_` is only created in the `fit_transform()` method (which is called by `fit()`).

Comment: I writed print(lsa.fit(X)) instead of lsa.fit(X). Following your advice, it works well. Thanks. Another question. Can I use this module in English and Korean mixed text? When I run this module, I get only english words result.

Comment: This happened to me when I was calling `transform`, not `fit_transform` - basically the model hadn't been `fit` yet.